# comparison of SGD and ALS in collaborative filtering

Tags: model-evaluation, stochastic-gradient-descent

Matrix factorization is widely applied in collaborative filtering, and briefly speaking, it tries to learn the following parameters:
$$\min_{q_u,p_i}\sum_{\{u,i\}}(r_{ui} - q_u^Tp_i)^2$$

And we could apply **SGD** and **ALS** as the learning algorithm, however, as I read [here](http://bit.ly/24WcjPg), they said,

> SGD is not practical if the dataset size is huge, instead ALS is better.

I wonder why SGD is not good if the dataset is huge? I thought even if it's huge, we could use mini-batch SGD, which is the widely adopted way to train large nerual nets, isn't it?

**FOLLOWUP**

By SGD, each time we only use one data point $r_{ui}$, and only optimize one part of the entire loss, i.e. optimize $(r_{ui} - q_u^Tp_i)^2$, so we update $q_u$ using the gradient of this part, resulting $\tilde{q_u}$.

Absolutely $\tilde{q_u}$ will optimize $(r_{ui} - q_u^Tp_i)^2$, but it might worsen other parts of the entire loss, say $(r_{uj} - q_u^Tp_j)^2$, I mean both $r_{ui}$ and $r_{un}$ involves $q_u$.

Considering the above case, how could we **guarantee that SGD will converge**?

Comment: SGD and ALS aren't the only approaches to matrix factorization. SVD is a third that may have computational advantages over the others, particularly for large datasets.

Comment: @DJohnson, yes you'er right, but here I just want to figure out more about SGD vs ALS :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both SGD and ALS are very practical for matrix factorization,

Yehuda Koren, a winner of the Netflix prize ([see here](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf)) and a pioneer in Matrix factorization techniques for CF, worked at Yahoo labs at the time, and was a part of the development of a CF model for Yahoo.

Reading through Yahoo labs' publications (for example [here](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~lzhen001/activities/KDD2011Program/docs/p141.pdf) and [here](http://www.ideal.ece.utexas.edu/seminar/LatentFactorModels.pdf)), it is easy to see that they are using SGD heavily, and we can only assume that the same holds for production systems.

Matrix factorization is often done on a matrix of `user_feature`x`movie_features` (instead of matrices of `users`x`movies`) because of the cold-start issue, making the argument mentioned in the link less relevant.

SGD also has the upper hand regarding dealing with missing data, which is a fairly common scenario.

To sum up, SGD is a very common method for CF, and I see no reason why it cannot be applied on large data sets.

Comment: Great hints, but I have a followup question about SGD's convergence when applied to MF, please see my post.

Comment: The `S` in the SGD stands for stochastic, You might have a few iterations in which you are stepping away from the local maximum, but on average, you are walking in the right direction.

Comment: Having said that, there are quite a lot of variation on GD that work better than SGD in some circumstances, for example, In the paper that Alex cited, Biased SGD had the best convergence rate among the algorithms they tested (ALS and SGD are listed there as well).

Answer (score 8):

Check out the comparison here:

[Recommender: An Analysis of Collaborative Filtering Techniques -Aberger](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2014/Christopher%20Aberger,%20Recommender.pdf)

The conclusion seems to be that biased stochastic gradient descent is generally faster and more accurate than ALS except in situations of sparse data in which ALS performs better.